# Exam Writing: Combining Topics on Exams in New Ways

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, exams

**The Question:** Does combining two or more topics into one question on a mathematics examination when the topics have not notably been combined in the course lecture, homework, or other assessments provide a good measure for any of the following points?

- Ability to combine knowledge quickly in a new situation.
- Demonstrate knowledge of all topics incorporated.
- Passing correctly demonstrates working knowledge of the topics more than independent questions on each topic.
- Failure correctly shows that the student might not posses the skills to succeed at later courses or does not have a working knowledge of the topics.

Any educational research included would be appreciated.

**Notes:** The exam is for undergraduate calculus students (first or second year university) who are not all assumed to be math or science students to provide a summative assessment of their knowledge thus far in the course (see [ME.SE Exam Philosophy](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/exam-philosophy/2119#2119) answer by Benjamin Dickman). We may assume that this is not a multiple choice exam.

**A Not Particularly Hard Example:**
Topics: Separable Differential Equations, Conic Sections

Sketch several solution curves to $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= -\dfrac{x}{2y}$.

**Removed:** *My department uses multiple choice for machine grading purposes (mandatory for this course), so particular answers with this in mind would be grateful but not fully necessary.*

Comment: Would passing this question be required to pass the course or just for those wanting maximum marks? With multiple choice, the validity of questions involving multiple steps or combining multiple topics is problematic. It is unclear exactly what failure would demonstrate. Of course, with multiple choice, success does not even demonstrate anything! It would seem best used as a formative assessment freed from your departments exam policy.

Comment: That's my issue with multiple choice as well, but there is no chance to get around that. That's why I left it more open to broader answers.

And correctly answering the question for maximal marks, but on the exam there would be several of such questions forcing the student to correctly answer many to get high marks.

Comment: i would say that if you haven't discussed similar problems with combinations of topics in class that it would be fruitless to give them during an exam, likely just frustrating students.  That being said, i would highly recommend going over these types of problems in class because it allows students to make connections between topics which makes the learning stick much better.

Comment: With several such questions, rather than a 'bonus questions', if there has been no homework or formative assessment on which students have had practice combining topics, the exam is trying to be an aptitude test rather than a summative assessment, making it invalid. Strategies to combine topics is in itself a skill that can be taught and practiced. I would expect maths majors to be able to do it, but science majors and others are in the course to learn a tool, and their ability to improvise mathematics in an exam situation does not seem relevant to the reason they are taking the course.

Comment: After the first year or so of writing my own exams, I concluded that it was (for me) not a good idea to have questions combining two or more nontrivial things.  Not even combinations we had done in class.

Comment: It sounds like you would like to assess two different things: mathematical content knowledge (second bullet point) and mathematical problem solving (first bullet point). Because problem solving requires mastery of the content knowledge, it would be difficult to identify the "source" of failure if all you presented were these mixed-topic problems on one exam. I would suggest having two sittings: a "traditional" multiple choice section to assess content knowledge, followed by an open-book mixed-topic problem section to assess problem solving/"working knowledge."

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I don't think that combining topics is necessarily a problem, as long as each step carries marks and errors are followed through. There are classes where ability to combine knowledge is a stated aim - leading to an hour long exam question. Students expect this and practice for it. Assessors then search students' solutions for evidence of specific skills. The correct final solution isn't required to pass the exam, and the exam is just one part of the course. I don't know how this could work in multi-choice exams.

Comment: I see now, based upon all your comments, that trying to work all of this in a multiple choice framework is most likely unfeasible. This leaves two questions then, how to maximize evaluation of the above points in a non multiple choice framework and the other is how to accurately test when multiple choice exams are used.

Comment: I have edited the above question to reflect no multiple choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still a comment, but expanded.  I wrote

> After the first year or so of writing my own exams, I concluded that it was (for me) not a good idea to have questions combining two or more nontrivial things. Not even combinations we had done in class.

For example: in integral calculus, computing an area in the plane.  I give them some equations describing a region in the plane, then ask them to compute the area.
**BAD IDEA**
There are two non-trivial steps: (1) find the integral to compute, then (2) evaluate the integral.  The problem for the grader (me): if there is an error in the first part, then the second part may become much easier, or much harder.  There is no sensible way to assign partial credit for that second part.

Instead of that, I would ask two questions.  One in which they find the integral to compute, but **do not evaluate it**.  Another in which they evaluate an integral.

I am talking about in-class time-limited exams.  Take-home problems (which we call "homework", and may or may not be graded) of course will include two- or three-part problems.